# How can I make Ajax and Struts2 together?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, struts2

I am a newbie and this is my first post, I am doing a simple project that combine ajax and struts. My code as below, my question is : After I got correct value(department) from Action on jsp page, the correct result will be refresh because of "return query;" in QueryAction.java, however, if I have to use "return query;" to get value for query.jsp....How can I solve it ?

query.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>

    <head>
    <s:head />
      <title>Query Page</title>
      <h1 align="center" id="h1"></h1>
    </head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

       <s:include value="/msg.jsp" />
       <s:form action="query" id="form">  
            <s:textfield name="name" id="name" label="Search the Department" />          
                    <s:submit value="Search" onclick="return myFunction()" id="submitRowAdd" />                    
       </s:form>

       <table border="1" id="depTable">
        <tr> 
            <td>Department ID</td>
            <td>Department Name</td>
            <td>Manager ID</td>
            <td>Repeal</td>
        </tr>           
       </table>
       <br>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    var btnAdd = document.getElementById("form");
    btnAdd.onsubmit = function(){
        var txtTd = document.createTextNode("<s:property value="did"/>");
        var eleTd = document.createElement("td");
        eleTd.appendChild(txtTd);  

        var txtTd1 = document.createTextNode("<s:property value="dname"/>");
        var eleTd1 = document.createElement("td");
        eleTd1.appendChild(txtTd1);  

        var txtTd2 = document.createTextNode("<s:property value="mid"/>");
        var eleTd2 = document.createElement("td");
        eleTd2.appendChild(txtTd2);  

        var txtTd3 = document.createTextNode("<s:property value="rep"/>");
        var eleTd3 = document.createElement("td");
        eleTd3.appendChild(txtTd3);  

        var eleTr = document.createElement("tr");
        eleTr.appendChild(eleTd); 
        eleTr.appendChild(eleTd1); 
        eleTr.appendChild(eleTd2); 
        eleTr.appendChild(eleTd3);

        var theTable = document.getElementById("depTable");
        theTable.appendChild(eleTr);                        
    }
</script>
```

QueryAction.java

```
package actions;
import com.Department;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import service.DepartmentService;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class QueryAction extends ActionSupport {

private String name;
DepartmentService ds;
long did;
String dname;
String mid;
char rep;
    private String result; 

public String execute() {   

    if(name != null && !"".equals(name)) {
        Long lname = Long.valueOf(name.trim());
        Department ppp = ds.findById(lname);
        if(ppp==null) {
            return "sss";
        }
        //did = ppp.getDepartmentId();
        //dname = ppp.getDepartmentName();
        //mid = ppp.getManagerId();
        //rep = ppp.getRepeal();

        JSONObject json=JSONObject.fromObject(ppp); //I run debug it fail on here !
                  result=json.toString();
                  System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +  result);
    } //return "result";
    return SUCCESS;                          
     }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public DepartmentService getDs() {
    return ds;
}
public void setDs(DepartmentService ds) {
    this.ds = ds;
}
public long getDid() {
    return did;
}
public void setDid(long did) {
    this.did = did;
}
public String getDname() {
    return dname;
}
public void setDname(String dname) {
    this.dname = dname;
}
public String getMid() {
    return mid;
}
public void setMid(String mid) {
    this.mid = mid;
}
public char getRep() {
    return rep;
}
public void setRep(char rep) {
    this.rep = rep;
}
    public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}


}
```

Comment: Include jquery as you would for a normal page, use jQuery.getJSON when you need an asynchronous request add the struts2-jquery-plugin to allow your actions to return json (it is quite easy to use).

Comment: Hi Quaternion, thanks your reply.I have modified QueryAction.java for adding json. I have import struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-plugin and json-lib.However,when I run debug mode,it failed on JSONObject json=JSONObject.fromObject(ppp); seems like con not find json...could you help me ?

Comment: A lot of things 1) You trim name and turn the string into an Integer, if you need an Integer just declare it as such.  2) Move validation into a method with the signature "void validate(){}" if there is an error, inside validate set an field error (look in ActionSupport for methods which set errors), if an error is set execute will not be called and "input" will be returned from the action which by default redirects back to the calling form. You should then add tags to show the field errors. 3) You are NOT using the struts2-json-plugin! Use it.